# addEventListener in a React app isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

**Some background:**
I'm trying to consume a **custom web component** in a react app and trying to listen to events from the web component. I believe you can't just handle the events in the usual react way on custom web component.

i.e.

```
<custom-button onClick={this.clickHandler}></custom-button>.
```

I have tried this and it didn't work.

**The problem:**
So, I'm trying to listen to an event via **addEventListener** as you would do in vanilla js but the event handler is never getting called.

An example of this is below. I know `<button/>` isn't a custom web component but it demonstrates the problem:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buttonRef = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // there are no errors attaching the handler
    this.buttonRef.current.addEventListener("onClick", e => {
      // this point is never reached
      debugger;
      console.log("onClick", e);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <button ref={this.buttonRef}>click me</button>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why you just don't use the `onclick` of the button, and passes the handler to it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The event is called [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click), not `onClick`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use an `eventListener` to do it. In `ReactJS`, you can use a `handler` to the button, like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  btnHandler = e => {
      console.log("onClick",e)
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.btnHandler}> click me </button>
  }
} 

export default App;
```

Take a look at the [ReactJS Handling Events docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Comment: First "Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.", now it's "Uncaught ReferenceError: btnHandler is not defined".

Comment: was my mistake, I wrote `'btnHandler'` instead of `{btnHandler}`. change it in your code and it should work. If doesn't, try `{this.btnHandler}`

Comment: @xehpuk, tested and working fine here. I edit the answer with the fixes.

Comment: Yes, now it's working. You don't need to bind `this` if you don't use it in the callback though.

Comment: Yeah. Will change it to arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two functionalities here,
**button** will only react to onClick events and your ref will only react to 'click' if the ref is clicked which it isn't.
So the button currently has no functionality.

From react doc:

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  // textInput must be declared here so the ref can refer to it
  let textInput = React.createRef();

  function handleClick() {
    textInput.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={textInput} />

      <input
        type="button"
        value="Focus the text input"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This a solution to your problem. Hope is the right solution.

Also
`<button onClick={this.onClick}>click me</button>`

can be written as:
`<button onClick={e => this.onClick({e, ...})}>click me</button>`

to have access to custom props you want to pass along to your button Event Listener.
In this situation you Event Listener needs to look like:

`onClick = (e, ...) => {
      // this point is never reached
      debugger;
      console.log("onClick", e);
  };`

Please note the `...` in there needs to be a `key => value` pair.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onClick = e => {
      // this point is never reached
      debugger;
      console.log("onClick", e);
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.onClick}>click me</button>;
  }
}
```

Also try not to use React References, unless you really need to. They are not intended to be used outside of React's core functionality.